# Can't get querying Mongo docs between dates to work

Tags: mongodb, rest

I've made a database of sensor data, which in essence stores Double values paired with Date timestamps.
I've tried querying them with what seems to be the right syntax, but it returns just [].

The API is made in MongoDB Stitch, and I'm calling it through Postman.
If I make my API return all documents, it works fine.

This is an example of a Document in my database:

```
_id:5caf026c8bc97c06677967d6
time:"2019-04-11T09:01:32Z"
val:102.85
topic:"pressure/stjernelaks/sensor0"
isotime:2019-04-11T09:01:32.000+00:00
```

Edit:
This is how the document looks when returned as Array through the API:

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5caf18078bc97c066779724a"
    },
    "time": "2019-04-11T10:33:43Z",
    "val": {
        "$numberDouble": "102.88"
    },
    "topic": "pressure/stjernelaks/sensor0",
    "isotime": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1554978823000"
        }
    }
},
```

And this is the query I'm making:

```
https://eu-west-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/semapres-charts-dsioa/service/get-chart-data/incoming_webhook/get-all-between?arg2=1554970464&arg1=1554980464
```

Alternatively I've used the arguments 2019-04-11T07:01:32.000+00:00 and 2019-04-11T09:01:32.000+00:00. It's the exact same format as in the database.
It's created by LocalDateTime with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME in Java, and my MongoDB says the data field type is Date, not String.

This is my webhook in all it's simplicity:

```
 exports = function(payload) {
  const {arg1, arg2} = payload.query;
  const contentTypes = payload.headers["application/json"];
  const body = payload.body;

 const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
 const mycollection = mongodb.db("pressure").collection("stjernelaks");
 return mycollection.find({
    isotime: {
        '$gte': new Date(arg1),
        '$lt': new Date(arg2)
    }
 }).toArray();
};
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't return any documents, so any help would be great.

Update:
I tried modifying my query to return documents with "val" inside a range. Also there was the same problem. Just as with the time and date string, I can use my webhook and hardcode the arguments, and it works. And I can make my webhook return the arguments, it reads them back to me without incident. But it just won't return any documents when it's making a query based on my arguments! It's bizarre!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$lte` instead of `$lt`

```
mycollection.find({
isotime: {
    '$gte': new Date("2019-04-11T07:01:32.000+00:00"),
    '$lte': new Date("2019-04-11T09:01:32.000+00:00")
}
```

})

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can we expect a different output with 'less than or equal' compared to 'less than'? It does give me a response!
But, using those strings as an argument does not work. So maybe my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to execute `$gte` and `$lt` with `or` case

Comment: I updated my question a bit. Your code works, hardcoding the date string. But it won't work sending the exact same string as an argument! Maybe I'm doing something wrong in Postman, is there any special configuration to consider?
The date must be in a range, so it must be greater than or equal & less than or equal. Since your code works it must be the right syntax there.